# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin(\frac{\pi}{6} - 2\text{exp}(i\theta)) d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

In one of my exercise sheets, I am asked to find $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-2\exp(i\theta))d\theta$

This follows a question asking to derive a form of Cauchy's theorem:

$f(a)=\frac{1}{2n\pi}\int_{0}^{2n\pi}f(a+r\exp{i\theta})d\theta$

But I can't even figure out how to start.

All help appreciated, please help me understand this!

Thank you.

EDIT:

So I understood part 1, deriving $f(a)=\frac{1}{2n\pi}\int_{0}^{2n\pi}f(a+r\exp{i\theta})d\theta$

Now I need to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}-2\exp(i\theta))d\theta$

Comment: Isn't the integral you are trying to evaluate almost exactly in the general form of part 1?

Comment: I know this in my head, even before you said it, but I'm just struggling to put it all together.

That is, I can't picture the function $sin(...)$, but I know my answer is in the form $2i\pi * y$ for some y=f(a)

Comment: I see it! Okay. Thanks for just helping me jog my brain a bit. $f(a)=sin(\frac{\pi}{y})$

Comment: What's $y$ by the way?

Comment: oops, i meant over 6

Comment: Note that you can get displayed equations by using double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs. Things like fractions and integrals with limits look a lot more readable and less squashed that way. About the question: has it been answered? If so, you could consider writing up the answer and accepting it to mark the question as answered. If not, I think you should clarify what questions remain after the exchange in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+r\exp{i\theta}=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\exp{i\theta}$, so $a=\frac{\pi}{6}$

Now we have $$2\pi f\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+r\exp{i\theta}\right)d\theta$$

So $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+r\exp{i\theta}\right)d\theta=2\pi\frac{1}{2}=\pi$$

as $f(a)=\sin(a)$

Comment: How did $2\mathrm i\pi$ get into the upper integration limit? and how did you arrive at $\displaystyle f\left(\frac\pi6\right)=\frac12$? By the way, you can get appropriately sized parentheses (in fact any paired delimiters) by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Typo, and explained at the bottom.

And thanks!

Comment: I think you have an excess factor of $\mathrm i$ in there. For $r\to0$, this should go to $2\pi f$, not $2\pi\mathrm if$. Also, if you derive this by substituting $z=\exp(\mathrm i\theta)$ and using the residue theorem, the factor $\mathrm i$ in the residue theorem cancels with the factor $\mathrm i$ from the substitution.

Comment: You're right, I misquoted Chauchy's formula.

Comment: The name is "Cauchy". Generally speaking, I would advise you to try to be less negligent; it wastes a lot more time having to find all the small mistakes you made than to focus on not making them. Did you see my comment about the appropriately sized parentheses?

Comment: Again, another typo. A lot on my plate at the moment.

Also, I tried to use it, but it wouldn't work for me.

Comment: OK, I adjusted the parentheses, you can take a look how it's done if you like.